# SSL routines:ssl23_write:ssl handshake failure:s23_lib.c:177:

Tags: openssl, openldap, certificate-authority, debian-jessie

I have an openldap master and 2 openldap slaves. Using a non self-sign CA.

> openldap master: name debian based on stretch
>   slapd 2.4.44+dfsg-5+d amd64
>   openssl 1.1.0f-3+deb9u1 amd64

---

> openldap slave: name debian1 based on stretch
>   slapd 2.4.44+dfsg-5+d amd64
>   openssl 1.1.0f-3+deb9u1 amd64

---

> openldap master: name ldap based o oracle linux 7.4
>   slapd 2.4.44-5.el7.x86_64
>   openssl-1.0.2k-8.0.1.el7.x86_64

openldap client based on oracle linux could not connect to ldap master based on debian strech.

Things that I have done at slave debian and slave oracle linux:

```
root@debian1:~# openssl verify -CAfile /etc/ssl/contatogs.com.br/cacert.pem /etc/ssl/contatogs.com.br/newcerts/cn\=debian1\,ou\=computers\,dc\=contatogs\,dc\=com\,dc\=br.crt.pem 
/etc/ssl/contatogs.com.br/newcerts/cn=debian1,ou=computers,dc=contatogs,dc=com,dc=br.crt.pem: **OK**

[root@ldap ~]# openssl verify -CAfile /etc/openldap/cacerts/cacert.pem /etc/openldap/certs/cn\=ldap\,ou\=>
/etc/openldap/certs/cn=ldap,ou=computers,dc=contatogs,dc=com,dc=br.crt.pem: **OK**
```

so far so good 80)

Now possibly problem at debian1 slave:

```
root@debian1:~# openssl s_client -connect debian.contatogs.com.br:389 -CAfile /etc/ssl/contatogs.com.br/cac
ert.pem  -state 
CONNECTED(00000003)
SSL_connect:before SSL initialization
SSL_connect:SSLv3/TLS write client hello
**SSL_connect:error in SSLv3/TLS write client hello**
write:errno=0
---
no peer certificate available
---
No client certificate CA names sent
---
SSL handshake has read 0 bytes and written 176 bytes
Verification: OK
---
New, (NONE), Cipher is (NONE)
Secure Renegotiation IS NOT supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
No ALPN negotiated
SSL-Session:
    Protocol  : TLSv1.2
    Cipher    : 0000
    Session-ID: 
    Session-ID-ctx: 
    Master-Key: 
    PSK identity: None
    PSK identity hint: None
    SRP username: None
    Start Time: 1519415735
    Timeout   : 7200 (sec)
    Verify return code: 0 (ok)
    Extended master secret: no
```

But master/slave with only debian/debian works despite this error/warning.

Now oracle linux does not work at all......

```
[root@ldap ~]# 
<contatogs.com.br:389 -CAfile /etc/openldap/cacerts/cacert.pem  -state
CONNECTED(00000003)
SSL_connect:before/connect initialization
SSL_connect:SSLv2/v3 write client hello A
139967037114272:error:140790E5:SSL routines:ssl23_write:ssl handshake failure:s23_lib.c:177:
---
no peer certificate available
---
No client certificate CA names sent
---
SSL handshake has read 0 bytes and written 289 bytes
---
New, (NONE), Cipher is (NONE)
Secure Renegotiation IS NOT supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
No ALPN negotiated
SSL-Session:
    Protocol  : TLSv1.2
    Cipher    : 0000
    Session-ID: 
    Session-ID-ctx: 
    Master-Key: 
    Key-Arg   : None
   PSK identity: None
    PSK identity hint: None
    Start Time: 1519415876
    Timeout   : 300 (sec)
    Verify return code: 0 (ok)
```

I am almost certain that problem is CA, but I don't know to fix...80)

Any help would be very appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Hi for future search I have found the correct way do get rid of this error. When I create the certificate for slave I created using client part ( TLS Web client) and the correct for is to create a certificate as server ( TLS Web server). What help me to discover this error was another post at serverfault w/ this command: openssl verify -purpose sslserver -CAfile cacert.pem ldaprov1.crt